# How can I have a class called "System", using C# 6.0

Tags: c#

I need to create and use a class that will be called System.cs (please don't ask why :-).

The current option is to refer it with the namespace, for example

```
NameSpace.System.Debug("Hi");
```

Putting it in namespace like

```
using System = NameSpace.System;
```

Does not work either.

All I want is to write some thing like `System.Debug("Hi")` and get my implementation called.

Jay

Comment: Why not just use `using MySystem = Namespace.System;` and then `MySystem.Debug("Hi")`?

Comment: Define *does not work*.

Comment: your class name should be more specific.

Comment: Don't say 'don't ask why', when it's probably the most relevant question. There is NO good reason for calling a class 'System', and even if there is, not referring to it by it's full namespace is a maintenance/debugging nightmare.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Don't do it even if you have to... If someone told you to do that, then explain that person that it will make the code harder to understand and to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace test
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Debug("things");
        }
    }

    public static class System
    {
        public static void Debug(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to work just the same whether the class is named `System` or `@System`, and whether I call `System.Debug("things")` or `@System.Debug("things")`.  Since `System` is not a keyword I don't think the `@` really does anything.

Comment: Yes it does, it makes confusing code even more misleading and confusing. Honestly, this shouldn't have been answered, showing people how to write bad code is inadvisable at best.

Comment: You're right, I actually misused @ here.  It seems the namespacing takes of it.
@Flynn1179  I'm pretty sure he knows its bad.